# How to create a GridLayout.LayoutParams to specify the position of a text view?

Tags: android, layout

To place a Text View dynamically onto a GridLayout I tried the following code:

```
GridLayout.Spec spec = new GridLayout.Spec(1,1);
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(spec);
```

yielding in an error:

```
Error:(129, 36) error: constructor Spec in class Spec cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Ok then, I tried the following code, following the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec.html), in which it says to use the following methods to create a spec:

```
GridLayout.Spec spec = new GridLayout.Spec();
spec.spec(1);
```

but this also is incorrect.

Now I am utterly confused. I do not understand what the documentation is telling me. Maybe the docs are outdated/incorrect? They do not even tall me what the `int` values signify!

I want to be able to set parameters for a `TextView`, like to column and/or the row where to place them, the height of the row the text size...

Maybe someone can show a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should use it:

```
View view; // the view that you wanna insert

GridLayout.LayoutParams params =
   new GridLayout.LayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());

params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 1);    // First cell in first row uses rowSpan 1.
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 2); // First cell in first column uses columnSpan 2.
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference

Comment: `TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(text);`

Comment: What does `this` refer to ?

Comment: `text.setLayoutParams()` triggers a NPE ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95852/discussion-between-alex-and-jdev).

Comment: Note that `view.getLayoutParams()` returns `null` if the view is not attached to a parent `ViewGroup` or has no LayoutParams set (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getLayoutParams())